# What are the best settings to design poster at 2.6m x 3.05m in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution, billboard

I have to design artwork to go on a sheet 3050mm wide by 2600mm high and placed on a building to be viewed at about 15-20 meters.

The scene will be a living room with pictures of various furnitures cropped and placed in the scene.

I don't really know how to set up my document to make it easier to edit as my PC is finding it difficult to handle such a large file.

I have it currently set at 150dpi. I'm thinking about reducing the scene in half so 1500 x 1300 and setting dpi at 300, so when I double the size it will half the dpi. Not sure if this is how it works or the final result will be the same. Any guidance would be great.

Comment: A duplicate of this? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/what-ppi-settings-should-i-use-to-print-a-poster-from-photoshop?rq=1

Comment: Take a look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65130/how-do-i-calculate-image-size-for-print/65138#65138

Comment: I asked this on my phone and it didn't suggest to look at these as similar. But these are a good read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best photoshop settings... Do not make in Photoshop. :o) Unless of course it it your only resource, or you are manipulating the images in specific ways.

Normally for adding texts and doing simple collages of photos try to use a vector based program and insert there your photos, so you have a resolution independent project. This way you have sharp texts all the way for example. You can for example link the images externally.

> 3050mm wide by 2600mm

**1)** If you still want to use Photoshop, you could make a file 3050x2600 pixel file and the final resolution would be about 25ppi, wich at that distance is lets say just ok. One pixel measuring one mm.

**2)** But lets try 2x. 6100 x 5200 px at 50 ppi at that distance is more than enough. This would be half mm. you can not see that pixel at 2-3 mts.

**3)** If your computer can handle this try 3x. A 9150 x 7800px at 75 ppi.  That could be viewed at 1m and still look good.

Edited:

Based on your comment on the performace of your computer, I would say you play with proportional values between 3050x2600px and 6100x5200 px.

Comment: "Best photoshop settings... Do not make in Photoshop" Made me chuckle

Comment: I'll edit and coment that part...

Comment: It would make more sense.. It's funnier how it is though.

Comment: If not in photo shop then what else?

Comment: @Rafael You're exagerating a bit with the Photoshop hate. At this resolution, vector or not, it doesn't matter much. Plus layer texts in a PDF from Photoshop are still vector to my knowledge (if not flattened).

Comment: It is not hate. :o) But it is probably an unconscious "agenda" for people using more suitable programs for each case. I really need to prepare a well written article about it. And  yeap, probably right about the texts. I'll make some tests.

Comment: @Aasim Azam if you only have Photoshop or is the only program you are comfortable using, **please use it**.  The other programs normally involve a workflow. a) Images b) Aditional elements like text. So you normally work lets say with Photoshop and then assamble your project in Ilustrator, or Indesign or Corel for example.

Comment: I normally use all the softwares you mention. Only problem is my system isn't all that great. I've already tried to in illustrator and in corel draw but it's just not the same. Is not easy to manipulate an image's perspective on illustrator and corel draw. The envelope tool doesn't work on images in corel and in illustrator it is counter intuitive.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit that part X-).

Comment: If your system is not very powerfull try option No. 2: 6100 x 5200 px

Comment: Going to be updating my system soon. So this won't be a problem in future. I can do all the editing at full res then downsample when exporting the final artwork. Thanks for your help

Comment: Although you have a workstation It has no sense in doing more than 150 ppi on that size. I would stop on 100ppi.